# Please explain what happens when I run this Makefile

Tags: make

I'm learning flex and (for really the first time) using the command line.

I created a Makefile to simplify my testing process but I don't understand why the commands are in reverse.

For instance, in the terminal the order is as such:

```
flex test.l
```

this creates the file `lex.yy.c`

then I compile that:

```
g++ lex.yy.c -ll -o test
```

The Makefile reads backwards:

```
test: lex.yy.c
     g++ lex.yy.c -ll -o test

lex.yy.c: test.l
     flex test.l
```

So what happens specifically when I run `make`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Makefiles follow this format (Makefiles should always use tabs instead of spaces, since it is required in most (if not all) implementations of `make`) :

```
target: dependencies
    operations to build target
```

- The target is what you're willing to build/compile/create. There may be several of them, and they should be built in the Makefile order, unless dependencies need to be met first. The **first** target in your file is called the **default target**, it is what `make` tries to build when you call it without arguments.
- The dependencies are the different pieces required to build a target.

In this Makefile, you have two targets:

- test
- lex.yy.c

Since `lex.yy.c` is a dependency required to build `test`, it'll be built first from `test.l`. Once it is generated, it'll be possible to compile `test`. Basically, `make`... :

- Tries to build `test`.
- Unresolved dependency. `lex.yy.c` does not exist (or has been updated), it needs to be built first.
- Reading operations to build `lex.yy.c`. Running `flex test.l` : `lex.yy.c` is built.
- All dependencies for `test` are met. Running `g++ lex.yy.c -ll -o test`.
- `test` is created.

*Additional info:* For more information about makefiles, I would recommend *The Linux Development Platform* by **Rafeeq Ur Rehman**. [Chapter 4: Using GNU Make](http://www.faqs.org/docs/ldev/0130091154_124.htm).

Comment: So does it have to be in reverse order, can I build lex.yy.c first then build test?  Thank you, btw!

Comment: You should add that the first target is the default target. It is made if one calls `make` without arguments. Apart from that the order of targets does not matter so much. That is actually the reason for the "reverse order" of the targets in the makefile of the OP.

Comment: @MayNotBe it doesn't matter what order the targets appear in the makefile, it only matters that you have the target and its dependencies proper.

Comment: You should note that at least for "tradional" makefiles, and maybe all makefiles, the lines for "operations to build target" have to start with an ASCII tab character. This can cause problems, as spaces and tabs can render identically on screnn.

Comment: @Tobias: Edited my answer, thank you. Bruce: Added information about spaces and tabs in Makefiles. I do believe that this is relevant for all makefiles, at least I've always seen it this way.

Comment: So let's say that I'm running this Makefile over and over as I change the `test.l` file.  If I don't remove the `lex.cc.y` file first, the Makefile as it stands will create test with the old one, whereas if I switch the order in Makefile `lex.yy.c` will be rewritten first.  Is that correct?

Comment: @MayNotBe: "If I don't remove the `lex.yy.c` file first, the Makefile as it stands will create `test` with the old one (`lex.yy.c`), .... Is that correct?" No, that's not correct. The line `lex.yy.c: test.l` says that `lex.yy.c` *depends on* `test.l`, so `lex.yy.c` needs to be recreated (remade) if `test.l` changes (more precisely, if `test.l` is newer than `lex.yy.c`). This is independent of the order of the stanzas (line groups) in the Makefile.

Answer (score 4):

Make calls the target `test` first, but `lex.yy.c` is a dependency.

So before perform the real execution, make analyzes your targets and all dependencies.
The first target is `test`, but before start to execute it, `lex.yy.c` is called.